# Lagrange interpolation graph

Tags: matlab, graphics, graph, interpolation, polynomial-math

Here is my code for Lagrange interpolation. I am calling a function named `polyinterp` that performs the interpolation.

I am trying to approximate the sin(*x*) in [-*π*,*π*].
If I use 12 points for interpolation the result I am getting is fine.
However If I try to use 200 points for the interpolation I cannot understand the graph as the green line is supposed to draw th sin(*x*) and the blue circles represent the points used.

```
x=linspace(-pi,pi,200)
target=sin(x);
figure('name', 'Polynomial Interpolation 200 points'); 
u=-pi:0.01:pi
output_2 = polyinterp(u,x,target);
plot(x,target,'o',u,output_2,'-')
axis([-pi,pi, -1,1]);
xlabel('x (radians)');    %  label the x-axis
ylabel('sine function');  %  label the y-axis
title('sin(x)');
```

[image]

For 12 point interpolation I change this line:

```
x=linspace(-pi,pi,12)
```

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably caused by the limited floating point precision. I don't know what exactly `polyinterp` does, but typically n points define a polynom of (n-1)-th order. In your case it is 199-th order. This means it has a x^199 term in it and your range for x is -3 to 3. Check `eps(3.^199)`, you get huge precision errors caused by floating point arithmetic.